# Querying for Content Views

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, data-views

in Marketing Cloud, I try to query for contacts who clicked on a specific link on a website and is hence stored in Content Views Data Extension.

We want to use that for a kind of scoring, however when just using click data views it is only available for links that are directly placed in an email - I used the following query for this:

```
 select
k.SubscriberKey,
k.eventdate as ActivityDateTime,
k.URL,
k.linkname,
b.EmailName as Channel,
c.PVSID as PersonID,
c.FirstName,
c.LastName,
c.Country,
c.Email


FROM _Click k with (nolock)
LEFT JOIN [HaysDEClientContact] c on k.SubscriberKey = c.SUBSCRIBER_KEY
LEFT JOIN _Job as b on k.JobID = b.JobID

WHERE
k.eventdate > DATEADD(day,-30,GETUTCDATE())
AND
k.URL LIKE '%http://hays.de/meinhays/meine-einstellungen-preference-center%'
```

I tried with combining ContentViews with my MasterData already, however this is not working since the user ID in ContentViews does not relate to my identifier...
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The [dataviews](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5) in SFMC are only for Mobile (specific DVs only) and Email, these do not track anything to do with CloudPages.

For general data collection in a CP you would need to use the '[Web Analytics Connector](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_wa_web_analytics_connector.htm&type=5)' to pull in the data from your existing Google Analytics (or similar service) on the Web page or set up the '[Web & Mobile Analytics](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_anb_web__mobile_analytics.htm&type=5)' solution inside SFMC for your cloud pages.

I have heard that there are limitations to the 'Web & Mobile Analytics' solution around diving deep into specific data - so my recommendation would be to set up Google Analytics and then either through the connector or other similar feed track your clicks that way.

If this is involving Einstein, you will likely need to connect the '[Content Views](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_content_views.htm&type=5)' DE back to the '[Customer Profile](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_customer_profile_de.htm&type=5)' DE matching on `user_id` to gather `email_address`.

I am not sure if this will provide exactly what you want though, as this is only showing those that viewed the content. You would likely need to create some combo of the Analytics solutions mentioned above and the Einstein data to get that.

Comment: Keep in mind, that using W&MA on Cloud Pages still requires the content catalogue to be configured for Einstein Recommendations, before data can flow into PI data extensions. Also pages tracked need to reference an ID of an item in catalogue. This can be a little tricky, but utilising [streaming updates](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_streaming_updates.htm&type=5), can help one out, as no additional data integrations are needed than Javascript collect and catalogue update codes.

Comment: Thanks you the input - however this does not have to relate to any cloud page - I implemented the collect tracking code on my website on all pages that I want to track. So I think what I need is really to connect my ContentViews to Customer Profile, however I am not sure about how to approach this, do you have anything to share here? Thanks!